# How to check a DOM element is inside a range

Tags: javascript, dom, range

How can I check that the node from the DOM tree is inside a specific range (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)? Of course, the node can be totally inside the range and partly inside range.

Comment: What do you mean by a range?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/isPointInRange

Comment: Have you tried the Range methods listed in that link?

Comment: Do you want to check whether the node is entirely contained within the range, partially contained within the range or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ## Example
>
> ```
> range = document.createRange();
> range.selectNode(document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0));
> bool = range.isPointInRange(document.getElementsByTagName("p").item(0),1);
> ```
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/isPointInRange

Answer (score 3):

There is also `Range.intersectsNode()` available.

> The **Range.intersectsNode()** method returns a boolean indicating whether the given `Node` intersects the `Range`.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/intersectsNode

Example:

```
var isNodeInRange = range.intersectsNode(node);
```